# Price not updated with price rule Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I have a prestashop website and on a product I apply a price rule with -2€ by product if the quantity is higher than 3. But when the user select 3 in the quantity selection of the product, the price is not updated (the user doesn't see the promotion).

However, if I put the minimum quantity to have the promotion to 1, the promotion is visible when the page is loaded, I deduce it's the script which update the price which doesn't work...

Someone know how to solve it ? Thanks

Version of Prestashop : 1.6.1.7

Comment: Have you put your price rule in the price tab of prestashop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution : I had commented the product tab but the function which update the price take the discount amount in JQuery from this tab. I put it in 'hidden' instead of remove it.